# How would I use a disc image with VirtualBox

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox

I plan to use clonezilla to create an image of a 15gb harddrive. Is it possible to use this image with virtual box to emulate said harddrive?

Answer (score 0):

i believe so you can see how people mount them in ubuntu here
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=872832

they are basicly compressed dd images, so you should be able to mount them directly as a disk image
http://www.ehow.com/how_12197027_convert-clonezilla-virtualbox.html